# Sending and receiving information with Kafka

Tags: c#, api, apache-kafka, async-await

Is it possible to use kafka like api?
It means to send a message and wait to receive the answer.

I have just started programming with Kafka and I have a question about sending messages and receiving processing results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Producers send events, and you can wait for an acknowledgement from  the broker server, yes.

No, you cannot await receiving the consumer in the same action, because that is a separate Kafka function, and consumers poll from topics, rather than listen to the client-local producer events.